# CouchDB parallel replications causes high cpu usage

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb, replication, pouchdb

I have a per-user DB architecture like so:
[image]

There is around 200 user DBs and each has a continuous replication link to the master couch. ( All within the same couch instance) The problem is the CPU usage at any given time is always close to 100%.

The DBs are idle, so no data is getting written/read from them.There's only a few KB of data per DB so I don't think the load is an issue at this point. The master DB size is less than 10 MB.

How can I go about debugging this performance issue?

Comment: Are you using CouchDB 2.1?

Comment: @AlexisCôté yes

Comment: Based on some suggestions for similar cases, I increased the max_dbs_open value which provided a slight improvement. But I still feel like I could run into major scaling issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at https://github.com/redgeoff/spiegel - it's a tool to handle many CouchDB replications in a scalable way. Basically it achieves that by listening to the _global_changes endpoint and creating replications only when needed.

In recent CouchDB versions (2.1.0+), the replicator has been improved, but I think for replicating per-user databases it still makes sense to use an external mechanism like Spiegel to manage the number of active replications.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reminder, there are some [security flaws](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-19046/Apache-Couchdb.html) in CouchDB 2.1.0 and you might need to upgrade to 2.1.1. Maybe you've been hacked [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49361676/3405291).