# Couchdb causes a "process flooding" with 100% cpu power consumption

Tags: couchdb, cpu-usage

Since a few days my couchdb v1.6.1 is starting continuously new processes consuming 100% of the cpu power. After a system reboot this behavior repeats. I added a screenshot showing the situation as displayed by "top". Does anybody know what this means and where I have to search for a solution in the underlying code.

The couchdb is the remote db (ubuntu 16.04) for an angular 1.6 web app with pouch as local db.

Additional information neccessary?

[system screenshot showing "top" display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y2cx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've likely been hacked, thanks to a serious [security flaw](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-19046/Apache-Couchdb.html) in CouchDB 1.6.1. Someone is probably mining bitcoin or similar on your server. Upgrade to CouchDB 1.7.1 or 2.1.1 or newer.

Comment: My couchdb is not that easy to reach from outside.I cannot exclude, yes, but not fully convinced at the moment.

Comment: Does anybody know what the top COMMAND message "imWBR123" means?

Comment: In the end I got my eyes opened enough and saw what was actually obvious: The couchdb was hacked by a monero miner. Thx for help.